# Good Software Design When Business Rules in Code Rely on Database Lookup Values

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns

Sometimes there is situations where I need to take a value from a database lookup table similar to:

```
Id | Description
----------------
1  | descriptive text for 1
2  | descriptive text for 2
```

The Id vlaue is often stored in a variable:

```
private int DB_LookUp_Id = GetIdFromDB();
```

This DB_LookUp_Id value is then used to perform validation or other business logic like:

```
if (DB_LookUp_Id == 1)
    return true
```

This code will break if the Id value changes from, say  1 to 3

What is a good way to eliminate this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a code-based key alongside the database ID that is static, we tend to use either Guids or enumerated values for this:

```
Id | Key | Description
----------------
1  | 1   | descriptive text for 1
2  | 2   | descriptive text for 2
```

Then in code you could have:

```
enum DescriptiveTextParts
{
    Part1 = 1,
    Part2 = 2,
}

if (DB_LookUp_Key == DescriptiveTextParts.Part1)
    return true;
```

Not sure if this is "best practice", but it works for us. Database primary keys do not always need to be known or used by the application, though most of the time they are.

Alternatively, if it's all just text, ship it all into a resource file. This gives you localisation, compile-time benefits, and performance benefits. To the detriment of database access to resource strings (pretty much no access), and ability to release new strings without re-compilation.

Comment: I like your answer, but I will add that you could also make your table a dictionary like object, where the primary key is not an auto incremented number or guid, and instead have something more descriptive like "USER_LOGIN_HELP" or some such. This is essentially resources.

Comment: Sorry, I agree. I was just adding some more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice that I have seen needs more semantic information in the database. Put all **[reference data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_data)** is put in a database and multiple tables are used to normalize the data.

Imagine an online ordering system that needs to know what state a customer is in and it needs to know what states are valid shipping locations.

1) You might have a database tables called STATES

```
  KEY | NAME
 --------------------
  AL  | Alabama
 --------------------
  AK  | Alaska
 --------------------
  PR  | Puerto Rico
 --------------------
```

2) Create a reference data object to wrap a row in the database.

```
class StateReference {
    string key
    string name
}
```

3) Create a relational table of shipping locations, called SHIP_LOC, and keyed by state code ('WA', 'OR, etc.)

```
  KEY | VALID_SHIP
 --------------------
  AL  | true
 --------------------
  AK  | true
 --------------------
  PR  | false
 --------------------
```

4) Now create a method like this:

```
bool isValidShippingLocation(StateReference object) {

     return dbLookup('SHIP_LOC', object.key)
}
```

The first advantage of this approach is that it moves hard-coded values out of the code and into a database, where they are much easier to find and easier to change. Also, referential integrity between tables can be enforced and that helps guarantee valid results.

Furthermore, reference data now has semantically meaningful names. Eliminates guessing about what a '1' or code 'X' in the source code means.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad pattern, in that it places a dependency on your C# code from your database in a way that making changes in the database has unintended consequences for how the code operates.

There are plenty of different approaches, but they're most appropriate given certain circumstances.  For example, if the DB_LookUp_Id is a primary key and there are a finite number of entries, it may map well to enums and derived classes and best served up through a factory pattern. If DB_LookUp_Id could span many rows and will continue to grow over the lifecycle of the application, a class structure to contain that logic might be more generic as opposed to derived classes. There are a lot of possibilities.

As a general standpoint, I would start with looking at the nature of what that data represents and what happens with that data over time. Once you can begin to pinpoint how that data will behave (as opposed to how its used), you will be in a better position to address that aspect of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if this database table were merely serving as a string table to hold some text alone, then what the other have said in regards to pushing this to resources, etc is the right answer.

But I suspect that is not the case.  Data can and does have special meaning to the business, whether we want it to or not.  What database doesn't have a column somewhere called STATUS with values like "P" for pending, "O" for open, and "C" for closed.  You can put those values into s STATUS_CODES table with CODE and DESCRIPTION columns (and you probably should), but it doesn't change the fact that somewhere in your application (or more likely, in dozens of applications) is code that makes logical decisions against "P", "O", and "C".

Your questions was

> This code will break if the Id value changes from, say 1 to 3.  What
>   is a good way to eliminate this problem?

The answer is what we call here a "DDT".  Don't Do That.  P must always be a P and must never be changed to something other than a P.  Period, end of sentence.  Don't get me wrong, these kinds of things, these magic cookies should be minimized, documented, and used with a layer of indirection in you applications (more in a moment).  But we all live in the real world with real systems.

When writing code for these kinds of values, you need to never hard-code these within your methods.  At a bare minumum it is a constant or enum.  I personally like to treat them as first-class citizens in my code object models.  For example, the STATUS value we saw before becomes an OrderStatus object.

```
class OrderStatus

   public static readonly OrderStatus ClosedStatus = new OrderStatus("C");

   public static readonly OrderStatus OpenStatus = new OrderStatus("O");

   public static readonly OrderStatus PendingStatus = new OrderStatus("P");

   public static OrderStatus FromCode(string code)
   {
      if (code == "C")
         return ClosedStatus;
      else if (code == "O")
         return OpenStatus;
      else if (code == "P")
         return PendingStatus;
      else
         throw something;
   }

   private string _code;

   private OrderStatus(string code)
   {
      // private so cannot be created externally
      _code = code;
   }

   public string StatusCode { get { return code; } }

   // etc, etc.  Helpful to make ToString() return the inner status code.

}
```

Then in your Order object you will have a property of type OrderStatus.  And you can perform your logic tests without hard-coding those pesky one-character column values that DBAs seem to love.

```
if (someOrder.Status == OrderStatus.Closed)
   MessageBox.Show("Cannot modify closed orders.");
```